# Is it possible to create a partial dacpac from a database using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dacpac, dlm

I want to create several dacpacs from a single database but each from different schema or group of objects. Is it possible to do this with T-SQL?

I have to create a system to distribute database structures among different locations and I need to do this via T-SQL?

Or if anybody has any idea or experience in this field I would appreciate it.

Comment: One simple way would be to copy the object sets to new databases and create dacpacs from those.  However I'm not aware of an interface to dacpac creation from T-SQL. You can do it from [powerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/extract-a-dac-from-a-database?view=sql-server-2017#ExtractDACPowerShell)

Comment: Why using  TSQL?

Comment: The requirement is to do this from within tsql code. I don't have access to powershell on the server.

Comment: You don't have to access power shell on any server, you can run sqlpackage or SSDT on any client PC.

Comment: Does it need to be dacpac? Is the target Azure SQL? There are many ways to migrate tables

Comment: The target is not Azure, however I will figure it out differently as I've learned it is not possible from TSQL anyway! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no SQL command to create a BACPAC file.

The utility responsible for creating these files is called [SqlPackage.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-2017#help-for-the-extract-action).

To only copy data for specific schemas, you will need to explicitly list these tables in the command arguments. See: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5052/restore-individual-tables-using-sql-server-bacpac/

Disclaimer:
It is possible to run these commands from within SQL Server using [`xp_cmdshell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  but I would not recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for your response